# Recursively search for a nested object in array and update its children

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to recursively search through an array for an object by its **unique id**, then push an object into its **parts** array, then return the entire array

For example, this is the array I want to search:

```
car =    [
    {
        id: 13,
        title: 'Component13',
        parts: [
           {
               id: 784,
               title: 'Component242',
               parts: [

               ]
           },
           {
               id: 9,
               type: 'mitigation',
               parts: [
                      {
                          id: 68,
                          type: 'mitigation22',
                          parts: [

                          ]
                      },
                      {
                          id: 88,
                          type: 'threat',
                          parts: [

                          ]
                      }
                ]
           }
      ]
},
{
    id: 3,
    title: 'Component13',
    parts: [
           {
               id: 60,
               title: 'Component34',
               parts: [

               ]
           },
           {
               id: 51,
               type: 'threat',
               parts: [
                      {
                           id: 38,
                           type: 'mitigation22',
                           parts: [

                           ]
                     }
               ]
          }
      ]
   }
]
```

And if I wanted to insert this object into the **parts** child array in id 38:

```
{
    id: 34,
    title: 'Component211',
    parts: [

    ]
}
```

... the result should be this:

```
  ...commented out the first block to save space
 {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Component13',
    parts: [
          {
              id: 60,
              title: 'Component34',
              parts: [

              ]
          },
          {
              id: 51,
              type: 'threat',
              parts:[
                   {
                        id: 38,
                        type: 'mitigation22',
                        parts: [
                             {
                                 id: 34,
                                 title: 'Component211',
                                 parts: [

                                 ]
                            }
                        ]
                  }
            ]
      }
   ]
}
```

What is the best way to do this considering that I might need to insert an object at any level on the car array?

My feeble attempt:

```
 const updatePart = (id, obj, car) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
        if (car[i].id == id) {
            car[i].parts.push(obj)
        } else {
            car[i].parts.map(function (item) {
                updatePart(id, obj, item)
            })
        }
        return car
    }
}

car = updateTree(id, obj, car);
```

Comment: IMO there's no reason to return the entire array. you can just use this function to modify it and, and you don't need to `car = updateTree(id, obj, car);` you can just `car = updateTree(id, obj, car);`

Comment: Also, you define the `updatePart` function but call `updateTree` which is undefined.

Comment: BTW, there's no reason to use `.map` and the `for` loop instead of just `.forEach` in both cases.

Comment: do you want to mutate the array or get a new one with updated items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to get a new array, you could map the objects with new `parts` properties.

```js
const
    update = (array, id, object) => array.map(o => o.id === id
        ? { ...o, parts: [...o.parts, object] }
        : { ...o, parts: update(o.parts, id, object) }
    );

var car = [{ id: 13, title: 'Component13', parts: [{ id: 784, title: 'Component242', parts: [] }, { id: 9, type: 'mitigation', parts: [{ id: 68, type: 'mitigation22', parts: [] }, { id: 88, type: 'threat', parts: [] }] }] }, { id: 3, title: 'Component13', parts: [{ id: 60, title: 'Component34', parts: [] }, { id: 51, type: 'threat', parts: [{ id: 38, type: 'mitigation22', parts: [] }] }] }],
    result = update(car, 38, { id: 34, title: 'Component211', parts: [] });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A mutating approach with a short circuit if the `id` is found.

```js
const
    update = (array, id, object) => array.some(o => o.id === id
        ? o.parts.push(object)
        : update(o.parts, id, object)
    );

var car = [{ id: 13, title: 'Component13', parts: [{ id: 784, title: 'Component242', parts: [] }, { id: 9, type: 'mitigation', parts: [{ id: 68, type: 'mitigation22', parts: [] }, { id: 88, type: 'threat', parts: [] }] }] }, { id: 3, title: 'Component13', parts: [{ id: 60, title: 'Component34', parts: [] }, { id: 51, type: 'threat', parts: [{ id: 38, type: 'mitigation22', parts: [] }] }] }];

update(car, 38, { id: 34, title: 'Component211', parts: [] });

console.log(car);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider a lookup object to store a flat list of references to the nodes in your tree:

```
let memo = {};
const buildMemo = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach(item => {
    memo[item.id] = item;
    if (item.parts) buildMemo(item.parts);
  }
};
buildMemo(car);
```

Now, if you need to do some operation on the node of your `car` tree with id = 34, you can get a reference from memo[34].  You would need logic to update memo if you add/remove/move nodes from the `car` array

Answer (score 0):

Your `updatePart` is expecting an array, but in your `map` you are using recursion sending objects. So you don't need to use `map` (or `forEach`, which would be best suitable here) at all:

```js
var car=[{id:13,title:"Component13",parts:[{id:784,title:"Component242",parts:[]},{id:9,type:"mitigation",parts:[{id:68,type:"mitigation22",parts:[]},{id:88,type:"threat",parts:[]}]}]},{id:3,title:"Component13",parts:[{id:60,title:"Component34",parts:[]},{id:51,type:"threat",parts:[{id:38,type:"mitigation22",parts:[]}]}]}];


 const updatePart = (id, obj, car) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
        console.log(car[i])
        if (car[i].id == id) {
            car[i].parts.push(obj)
        } else {
                updatePart(id, obj, car[i].parts)
        }
    }
    return car
}

const obj = {
    id: 34,
    title: 'Component211',
    parts: [

    ]
}

car = updatePart(38, obj, car);

console.log(car)
```

Other errors in your code are`return car` inside loop, you should return after loop completes and you declared `updatePart` not `updateTree`.